How to get a function call argument string name, inside the same function. Using that as "extra parameter", avoiding adding an extra parameter
Having any Python function as:
def function1(param1, param2):  
    #...
    return 0

How would be possible to get a param string name (variable name) used in the function call? ideally getting this information in a simple way without the need to import extra libraries/modules, in order to keep the function process without adding a significant extra load, keeping all as efficient as possible. Ideally.
In the next example function1.__code__.co_varnames gets the original function parameters names:
"param1, param2"
But, what trying to get here is not that information. instead of that, the information to get is:
"var1, var2"
Getting this inside the same function.
def function1(param1, param2):
    print(function1.__code__.co_varnames)
    
    '''
    ...
    if param2_name == X:
      do something.
    elif param2_name == Y:
      do something else.
    '''
    
    return 0

var1 = 1
var2 = 2
var3 = function1(var1, var2)

As you can see in the function, the purpose to get the argument name inside the function is to use that string name for decision purposes.
By the way, yes, this could be done with "just" adding an extra parameter, but the reason for all this is precisely to avoid adding an extra parameter in the function. Due requirements, in this case an extra parameter is not a solution.
Thank you
UPDATE 1:
What trying to achieve here is just to keep an existing function call syntax but at the same time that the function be able to detect a kind of context that its previous code was not made to detect. So that's the main reason because adding an extra parameter for that purpose would not be a solution, because it would need to modify a current call syntax.
UPDATE 2:
I created a new thread with more details, about other possible solutions for the main situation where a function can identify the working context without the need to specify that context with a new parameter:
How a function could identify the type of working context, without specify it with a new parameter, keeping the existing function call syntax

Why do you want to do this? What are you really trying to achieve?

very vague but maybe you want **kwargs

@Wizard.Ritvik No, that would still return param1, param2, they want the caller's variables var1, var2.

This simply isn't possible. When you call a function, only the values are passed, not the expressions used to generate the values. What would you expect from function1(1+2, 3+4)? There are no variables.

Perhaps you should send the names as well: function1({var1:1}, {var2:2})

That is not at all how interpreters or compilers work. Expressions undergo reductions that lose everything, like 3+3 becomes 6, and you lose the 3's. They are gone, altogether. Passing an argument is just a variable reference that "reduces" into a value.

@ndc85430, the purpose is just to have a kind of context inside the function, but without the need to add an extra parameter to know that context, so if the function already has 2 parameters, then no need to add another parameter. As mentioned, this could be achieved by adding another parameter in the function but that's exactly what trying to avoid.

Unfortunately, that's not how function calling works. Look at the disassembled byte code of the caller. The variables are simply not stored anywhere.

@Barmar, the question is made precisely because the kind of situation you mention is already taken into consideration. In this specific case, the function will always receive variables as arguments. Here, what looking for, is the variable name (the string) of the argument.

I completely understand what you're trying to do. Like I said above, it's not possible.

@Barmar, thanks for staying tuned. Please read the "UPDATE 1" in the main question, to see if it could arise other kind of solution, other than the initial idea to work with the argument variable name.

@codev or this could be achieved by designing your program to have proper abstractions. In general, there are very few good reasons for a function to know anything about the actual variable names. Don't put data in variable names. Variable names exist only for the person reading/writing the code.

Rather vague, but maybe you are looking for **kwargs:
>>> def func(**kwargs):
...     if 'param1' in kwargs:
...         print('1:', kwargs['param1'])
...     if 'param2' in kwargs:
...         print('2:', kwargs['param2'])
...
>>> func(param1='test')
1: test
>>> func(param2='hello')
2: hello

Based on @Barmar's comment, a "clean" way I can think to do is with locals():
>>> def func(_locals):
...     if 'var2' in _locals: print('var2:', _locals['var2'])
...     if 'var1' in _locals: print('var1:', _locals['var1'])
...
>>> var1='test'
>>> var2='hello'
>>> func(locals())
var2: hello
var1: test


But they want to call the function with any variables, and have it print the names of those variables. The use case is a logging function.

@Barmar that’s gonna be… harder

@Wizard.Ritvik, thank you for the answer, but unfortunately the 2 given options get the variable value, and the goal in the main question is get variable name used as function argument in the function call, but, ...

but, ... after reading the comments about it by @Barmar, it seems it would need another way to get the same result.

...  also the comment by @doug65536.    (the comment-box here only allows 1 mention per comment)
